# Attacking the raider?

Tags: kabaddi

(Newbie in kabaddi)

In kabaddi, the raiders job is touch the opponent and comeback. But how does the referee decided who touched whom (if A touches B, it can equivalently be interpreted as B touches A). Using this loophole, why do the defenders wait, why don't they directly tackle the raider as soon as he enters?

Answer (score 2):

Raiders are known to score from significant distances even after the tackle has begun: the raider doesn't have to get out of the tackle, they just have to touch their own court before it's complete.

Allowing defenders to get anywhere near the midline makes a two-point raid (or worse) extremely easy to complete. What you suggest would make the **raider's** job easier, which is precisely the opposite of what the **defenders** want.